# Is there a way to extract the geometry from a Path?

Tags: java, android

It seems that once the points, arcs etc. have been added to a `Path`, the only way to assert its content is to draw it. Neither`Path` itself , or anything else in the `android.graphics` package seem to have accessors to the internal representations.

Is there a way to access the primitives? Any representation would be fine - points, segments, splines.

Thank you

Comment: Path is a thin wrapper around native impl. and contains only a handle. You can override each method of Path and impl. your own logic for tracking (after calling the `super`), cumbersome...

Comment: @bestsss Thanks, though it's a pity. I would rather avoid the magic of internal tracking with a derived class and continue with external tracking.  Good to know though that it's not me having missed the key method.